# how to persist child entity when parent is deleted

Tags: hibernate

I have two entity associated with bi-directional one-to-many. I want both to be independent.
For example Employee and Project is associated with one-to-many relationship but when I delete Project I want associated Employee data should be persist with project_id as null.

How to achieve this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it possible to manage both entities independently you have to remove constraints on db level. But be careful it could lead to inconsistent behaviour and loosing db consistency. 
You could programmaticaly control consistency.